# How to add React tooltip on top of JSP?

Tags: reactjs, jsp, hover, tooltip, integrate

I have built rich tooltip in React and now I would like to add it to one of the divs in JSP. Since the app is big and I don't have much time to rewrite JSP into React I would like to know how can I grab that div in JSP and add a tooltip on hover.

Unfortunately, I was not able to find a proper answer on SO.